# Submit a form without submit button and without page refresh?

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have a form which I cannot change and I have to handle its submit function from jquery only.

The form have radio buttons only. I want to submit the form without the page refereshed when a radio button is checked.

Here is the code which i tried.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      $('form#my-form').submit(function(){
        alert('form submitted');
      });
    }
});
```

It should alert the "form submitted" but it does not.

Any thing which I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with `"submitted"`? Do you want the information in the form to be sent with ajax to somewhere, or do you want the information in the form to be added to the HTTP_POST?

Comment: use $.post and use e.preventDefault() for prevent submission or use simple button instead of submit button. Yes, You need to write some javascript but it's work definitely as your requirements.

Comment: try to look at ajaxSubmit from http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: But you did not explained where you will submit your form's data, what script will use them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to submit the form without pageload, then you need to go for ajax.

If you want the alert while submitting, you need to modify ur code a bit..

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      $('form#my-form').submit();
    }
});

$('form#my-form').submit(function(){
        alert('form submitted');
      });
```

Comment: you need to call submit function inside if condition. And then, you need to write trigger for submit function outside of it  like i did above.

Comment: Does this submit the form twice?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7V2U/). My code will submit the form on check of a radioButton.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      $('form#my-form').submit();
});​
```

If you'd like *to alert anything on submit* of your form you have to add this code

```
$("#my-form").submit(function() {
    alert("submitting form ...");        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well - just make sure you put this code inside document.ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
          $('form#my-form').submit(function(){
            alert('form submitted');
          });
        }
    });
})
```

Please note that this selector is looking for ALL radio buttons. Also if you don't need to refresh page - you should add return false; to submit function.

But remember that is your case you need to click on radio button first to make you submit function working.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your IF says: "If the form is submited then alert user". So you have to submit the form manually when the radio control is checked.

Before closing the IF, enter the following code:

```
$('yourForm').submit();
```

Comment: If I used the `$('form#my-form').submit()` then it submit the form but  with a page refresh which I does not want.

Comment: Then, use Ajax. It is the only method for you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you just listen for the submit event. If you want to trigger the submit event you have add this line:

`$('form#my-form').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

Because you want your page to not be refreshed, use Ajax, here is the official documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/